Unable to open ClickOnce application by double clicking on an associated file type if the file is a UNC path
I have a clickOnce application with an associated file type and if I double click on an associated file the application opens properly and reads the file.
However...

if that file is opened via a UNC file path (e.g. \\myNetwork\myFiles\myFiles.stuff) the applicaiton will still open but I get an error that the file cannot be found.
Creating a network mapping (e.g. y: = \\myNetwork\myFiles) and opening it (y:\myFiles.stuff) will open the file correctly, but the non-mapped UNC path will not.
Opening my program and then choosing "file -> open" will successfully read from the UNC path

if feels like a permission issue when launching the application...  any thoughts?

Exactly what version of .NET are you using?

I'm using .Net 4.8
